# Delete rows with negative values

Tags: r, row

In R I am trying to delete rows within a dataframe (ants) which have a negative value under the column heading Turbidity. I have tried

```
ants<-ants[ants$Turbidity<0,]
```

but it returns the following error:

```
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(ants$Turbidity, 0) : < not meaningful for factors
```

Any ideas why this may be? Perhaps I need to make the negative values 
NA before I then delete all NAs?

Any ideas much appreciated, thank you!

@Joris: result is

```
str(ants$Turbidity)
```

num [1:291] 0 0 -0.1 -0.2 -0.2 -0.5 0.1 -0.4 0 -0.2 ...

Comment: I'm think you meant `>` when writing `<`.

Comment: Yes you are quite right, my mistake, one of many I think!

Comment: I meant the original ants$Turbidity, not the converted one. The one you give here can't give that error. But as you indicated yourself, using `header=T` seems to solve it, so don't bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marek is right, it's a data problem. Now be careful if you use [as.numeric(ants$Turbidity] , as that one will always be positive. It gives the factor levels (1 to length(ants$Turbidity)), not the numeric factors.

Try this :

```
tt <- as.numeric(as.character(ants$Turbidity))
which(!is.na(tt))
```

It will give you a list of indices where the value was not numeric in the first place. This should enable you to first clean up your data.

eg:

```
> Turbidity <- factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,"a"))
> tt <- as.numeric(as.character(Turbidity))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> which(is.na(tt))
[1] 11
```

You shouldn't use the `as.numeric(as.character(...))` structure to convert problematic data, as it will generate NA's that will mess with the rest. Eg:

```
> Turbidity[tt > 5]
[1] 6    7    8    9    <NA>
Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a
```

Comment: Thank you Joris and Marek. I have run this as suggested and indeed all of my rows are returned as character, at least none are returned as numeric. Now I have established that my data are in completely the wrong format, can you suggest how I can change them to numeric values or is it not that simple? Many thanks.

Comment: @Joey: So you mean that after which(!is.na(tt)) you get a list from 1 to the number of rows? If so, could you put the output of `str(ants$Turbidity)` in your question?

Comment: huh? That's a numeric vector. You can't get an error from that as you described. But you indicated yourself that the problem was the column headers, so using the option `header=T` solved the problem then I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Always do `summary(ants)` after reading in data, and check if you get what you expect.

It will save you lots of problems. Numeric data is prone to magic conversion to character or factor types.

Comment: Oh dear, I now see none of my columns of data (all numeric) have imported as numeric. I feel I have missed something fundamental when importing them. How do I specify that I want certain columns to be either Date, Time or numeric please?

Comment: @Spacedman: there is nothing magic to the conversion. If it gets converted to character or factor types, there is a problem in the data in the first place.

Comment: @Joey : the conversion is due to the fact that there are non-numeric characters in your dataset. If it would be possible, R would have made them numeric. You have to remove those non-numeric characters.

Comment: @Joey How you read them? Maybe you choose wrong version of `read.csv`? See help to `read.table` and description of `colClasses` argument.

Comment: @Spacedman I usually use `str` cause on large datasets `summary` could be overkill.

Comment: Just thought, could it be that my header row is causing the conversion? I have re-read in the data specifying column names this time, which I think has gotten rid of the non-numeric characters. I tried the initial arguement again in my original question and no error shows. It returns all those values larger than zero. Does anyone know how I can adjust this to include zero values please?

Comment: Great, thank you everyone, especially Joris! So, does anyone know the acceptable syntax for a "equal to or greater than" symbol in R. Right now I have just greater than >, I want >= but this isn't recognised?

Comment: @Joey : >= should work. Sure you didn't try => ? (the latter one gives an error)

Comment: Sorry, one more thing...if it was a range of values I wanted to keep, i.e. >= 0.9 and <= 1.1 inclusive, how would I code for this? I have tried 0.9:1.1, also tried indexing the vectors, like x[x>3&x<5]

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**. I forget about `as.character` conversion (see Joris comment).

---

Message mean that `ants$Turbidit` is a `factor`. It will work when you do

```
ants <- ants[as.numeric(as.character(ants$Turbidity)) > 0,]
```

or

```
ants <- subset(ants, as.character(as.numeric(Turbidity)) > 0)
```

But the real problem is that your data are not prepared to analysis. Such conversion should be done in the beginning. You should be careful cause there could be non-numeric values also.

Comment: `as.numeric` will give factor levels, not the numeric value. If you use `as.numeric(as.character(ants$Turbidity))`, you'll get problems with` NA`.

Comment: Thank you, this works well, I realised I want to actually want to keep everything greater than or equal to 0.0. When you say this type of conversion should be done at the beginning...at the beginning of what? Sorry, I'm fairly new to R and not used to some of the best practice...thanks :)

Comment: @Joris Obvious thing but I missed it. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work using the tidyverse (assuming column is the correct data type).

```
ants %>% dplyr::filter(Turbidity >= 0)
```